# How to link objects to columns in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, rest

I have two types of objects, `Categories` and `Products`. Here are their structures:

```
public class Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Categories
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Categories> ChildCategories { get; set; }
    public List<Products> ProductList { get; set; }
}
```

Products have a `name`, `desc`, `price` and a `category` they belong to.

Categories have a Name, list of child categories and a list of products that have that `CategoryId`.

I am trying to get this to work through a REST service. So for example, when you perform a GET on a Category, I want all the fields for that obj to show up, plus the products that share that Category Id show up in my JSON response. I am having trouble setting up the Model classes so they link together properly when I do a code migration and create the DB tables. Can anyone lead me in the right direction? I tried the following but it created a mess in my tables:

```
public class Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }

    public Categories Category { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the class at least which table it should match in the database and what the primary key is. Also, the `public Categories Category { get; set; }` will be problematic since your database surely does not now what the `Categories` type is.

Your product class should look something like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("Products")]
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fluent api configuration to set exactly tables that you want:

Example:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category{get;set;}
}

public class ProductConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
   public ProductConfiguration()
   {
       ToTable("Products");
       HasKey(c=>c.Id);
       Property(c=>c.Id).HasDatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);       
   }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
   public CategoryConfiguration()
   {
       ToTable("Categories");
       HasKey(c=>c.Id);
       Property(c=>c.Id).HasDatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
       HasMany(c=>c.Products).WithRequired(p=>p.Category).HasForeignKey(p=>p.CategoryI);
       HasMany(c=>c.ChildCategories).WithOptional(c=>c.ParentCategory).HasForeignKey(p=>p.ParentCategoryId);
   }
}
```

you should register this classes in dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoryConfiguration());
   modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProductConfiguration());

}
```